# Azure Pipelines conditions

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have setup a flow where azure release definition makes to an agentless API call to azure build pipeline which performs a list of tasks which trigger a release.

I would like to add a condition to the azure build pipeline to differentiate between a user running the build pipeline manually (through portal) or if the pipeline was triggered via an api call.

What is the neatest way to do this? Ideally I expect a condition something like

- eq(triggered-by, "Joe") -> not ideal, I don't want to attach condition based on a users name
- eq(build-reason, "api")  -> ideal but is there some in-build condition for something like this?

One other options which passes through my mind is passing a custom runtime variable through the api call, but I was wondering if there was a more in-built approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there's no build-in feature in Azure DevOps to achieve this.

We cannot judge whether it is triggered by manually or API. If you are using an API call, the token also stands for a single user.

Also, you could raise a feedback ticket for your demand: [Suggest a feature - Visual Studio (Windows) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/suggest-a-feature?view=vs-2022)